# What is an untouched libary code?

Tags: normalize

https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css

This is an important note in normalize.css on github.

"It is recommended that you include the normalize.css file as **untouched library code.**"

I want to understand what does it mean?

Thanks.

Comment: It means include it as it's provided, i.e. don't edit/add/remove anything to/from it.

Comment: Exactly as Alex K. said. They author of Normalize.css (GitHub user necolas) is saying that it's important that you don't alter their code after you've added it to your project.